# Memcache works on localhost (without anything in settings.py)

Tags: django, heroku, memcachier

My question is "can anybody corroborate or explain?"
The following caching logic works as expected on localhost, but
fails on heroku (queries every time):

```
from django.core.cache import cache
QUEUE_KEY = "queue"
def index(request):
  queue = cache.get(QUEUE_KEY)
  if not queue:
      queue = QueueItem.objects.order_by("id")
      cache.set(QUEUE_KEY, queue)
  c = {'queue': queue}
  return render_to_response('index.html', c)
```

Comment: How does it fail? Any error and trace?

Answer (score 0):

The cache works on localhost because Django uses local memory caching per default as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching).

I am assuming you followed [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-memcache) but did not configure your `CACHE` in your `settings.py` to use the MemCachier add-on. I just did the same and yes, it does not use the cache on Heroku. To answer @dahrens comment, there is no error. I am assuming that Heroku just disallows local memory cache or mocks it to always return empty.